# Attempting to read and download Outlook emails in jupyter notebook using win32

Tags: outlook, jupyter-notebook, win32com

Two-fold issue: 1) Trying to download attachments from Outlook emails using win32 in Jupyter Notebook  2) I get notifications of different lessons and resources by phone. Then I usually, send the URL to the resource to my email to organize later on. Is there a way to use Jupyter Notebook to grab these emails and store them in an excel file? Here is the lesson I am trying to follow currently: https://towardsdatascience.com/automatic-download-email-attachment-with-python-4aa59bc66c25 . And here is my code:

```
import win32com.client 

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") 
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
messages = inbox.items 
message = message.GetFirst()
attachments = message.Attachments 
attachment = attachments.Item(1) 
attachment_name = str(attachment).lower() attachment.SaveAsFile(path + '\\' + atttachment_name) 

exit
```

Comment: It seems you just need to iterate over all items instead of getting the first one by using the `message.GetFirst()` method, right?

Comment: the error seems to come up with the lines of code that say attachment(s). I could isolate each line to see if there's a specific line throwing the error. But I wanted to see the result of 1 email before doing it over more emails. **EDIT** The first error comes at: 'attachment = attachments.Item(1)'

Answer (score 0):

You never check that a message has attachments `(message.Attachments.Count > 0`) and you assume that you get a particular message from the Inbox: can either get the currently selected message (`Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection) or you need to search for the particular message using `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`. `Items.GetLast` will give some undetermined item.

Thirdly, the line `message = message.GetFirst()` was probably meant to be `message = messages.GetFirst()`. Still won't work, but at least it won't blow up because message variable is uninitialized.

Comment: Not sure that I follow the first part. The message.Attachments.Count > 0 will let me know if there are emails with attachments? I ran that and got False although there's an email with an attachment at the top of my inbox. How exactly would I use the Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection because it returns an error of "name Application is not defined". But in the second paragraph, you're correct. That was a typo when I wrote it into Stack. Also tried to do Items.GetFirst and that returned an error that "Items is not defined"

Comment: What you see in Outlook is not what `Items.GetFirst()` returns. What you see in Outlook depends on how you sort the items. Your code, however, never sorts the `Items` collection. `Application` object is what `win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")` returns.